# Explain the Module Contact Form on Prestashop

Tags: prestashop-1.7, prestashop-modules

I am reading Contact Form Module and although everything is very clear I can't understand why Configuration::updateValue( self::SEND_CONFIRMATION_EMAIL, Tools::getValue(self::SEND_CONFIRMATION_EMAIL) ); does not been saved on Configuration table...

Presta 1.7.7.0

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that you have checked the right row in the configuration table?
In the beginning of the contactform.php, is defined the constant

```
const SEND_CONFIRMATION_EMAIL = 'CONTACTFORM_SEND_CONFIRMATION_EMAIL';
```

So, if do you want to check the `self::SEND_CONFIRMATION_EMAIL` value, you need to search for CONTACTFORM_SEND_CONFIRMATION_EMAIL in table